# Unit Test Not Reach 100% Coverage IF/ELSE Not Taken in Imports

Tags: react-native, jestjs, code-coverage, istanbul

The Unit test with jest / Enzyme or React-Native-Testing-Library never reaches 100% of code coverage for problems with the import, some import show warning IEEIEIE if/else not taken

These modules are in node_modules (and node_modules is include in the coveragePathIgnorePatterns and exclude from collectCoverageFrom) or custom modules that do not even have if / else statements

```
import React from 'react';
import { cleanup, render } from 'react-native-testing-library';
import ItemListaComprobante from './ItemListaComprobante';

describe('test container ConfiguracionPin', () => {
    let wrapper;
    const props = {
        label: 'Test',
        value: 'Test',
    };
    afterEach(() => cleanup);
    beforeEach(() => {
        wrapper = render(<ItemListaComprobante {...props} />);
    });
    test('test container ConfiguracionPin render properly ', () => {
        expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
    });
});

import React, { memo } from 'react';
import { Text } from 'react-native'; // (without IEEI)
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { // IEEI
    Left,
    Right,
    CardItem,
} from 'native-base';

const propTypes = {
    label: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    value: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};

const ItemListaComprobante = ({ label, value }) => (
    <CardItem
        bordered
        borderedWhite
    >
        <Left>
            <Text>{label}</Text>
        </Left>
        <Right>
            <Text
                bold
                numberOfLines={1}
                ellipsizeMode="tail"
            >
                {value}
            </Text>
        </Right>
    </CardItem>
);

ItemListaComprobante.propTypes = propTypes;

export default memo(ItemListaComprobante);
```

My settings of jest

```
module.exports = {
verbose: true,
preset: 'react-native',
testEnvironment: 'jsdom',
transform: { '^.+\\.js$': '<rootDir>/node_modules/react-native/jest/preprocessor.js' },
setupFiles: ['<rootDir>/jest.setup.js'],
transformIgnorePatterns: ['/node_modules/*.js'],
coveragePathIgnorePatterns: [
    '<rootDir>/index.js',
    '<rootDir>/App.js',
    '<rootDir>/commitlint.config.js',
    '/node_modules/',
    'jest.setup.js',
    'ReactotronConfig.js',
    'LogUtils.js',
    'jest.config.js',
    'rn-cli.config.js',
    'transformer.js',
    'super-wallet/coverage/lcov-report',
    'Str.js',
],
setupFilesAfterEnv: [
    '<rootDir>/__mocks__/react-native-camera.js',
    '<rootDir>/__mocks__/react-native-fetch-blob.js',
    '<rootDir>/__mocks__/react-native-firebase.js',
    '<rootDir>/__mocks__/react-navigation.js',
    '<rootDir>/__mocks__/react-native-reactotron.js',
    '<rootDir>/__mocks__/react-native-user-agent.js',
    '<rootDir>/__mocks__/osiris.js',
    '<rootDir>/__mocks__/react-native-check-app-install.js',
    '<rootDir>/__mocks__/react-native-image-crop-picker.js',
    '<rootDir>/__mocks__/react-native-app-link.js',
],
collectCoverageFrom: ['**/*.{js,jsx}', '!**/node_modules/**', '!**/vendor/**'],
coverageThreshold: {
    global: {
        branches: 80,
        functions: 80,
        lines: 80,
        statements: -10,
    },
},
```

};

My settings of babelrc

```
    {
  "presets": ["module:metro-react-native-babel-preset"]
}
```

I would appreciate very much if somebody can help me, I have reviewed documentation of jest / istanbul and enzyme and I have not seen anything, even here I have also searched in case someone has had the same problem as me

This is error in istanbul coverage

[Istanbul Report Printscreen error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KT2qS.png)